# Field-level validation in Django REST - checking that field value is actually valid

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django 1.10 project and a model like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    #...
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, ...)
```

...and a serializer in which I want to perform a check like this (I provide a pseudo-code because I've got no idea how to write native Django code):

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_student(self, value):
        if invalid_value_is_provided_for_student:
            value = 666
        return value
```

And most importantly, I want to re-assign a specific value to the field in case invalid value has been provided (in the example above, I assign 666 to it). 
One way to do this that occurred to me is:

```
   def validate_student(self, value):
        if value not in University.objects.values('id'):
            value = 666
        return value
```

...which seems to be a bit dirty. I have a feeling that Django has a native more elegant way to implement this using exception handling. Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a custom manager method.

Comment: Or a `try: except:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to write any extra codes for that because you are creating the serializer by extending `ModelSerializer`. So that your serializer contains the default validation for university field provided by restframework. remove the validators and try to add some students with existing and non existing university id fields.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    #...
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, ...)
```

serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

leave the validation part to `serializers.ModelSerializer`. What happens here is ModelSerializer creates `university` attributes inside your serializer  like
`university = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=University.objects.all())`
Which is sufficient for the validation

**UPDATE #2** based on the comment

For that requirement, you have to override the university field in the StudentSerializer class. Then you have to implement the model linking on create method.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    #...
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, ...)
```

serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    university = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        university_id = validated_data.pop('university')
        try:
            university = University.objects.get(id=university)
        except University.DoesNotExist:
            # default 
            university = University.objects.get(id=666)
        return Student.objects.create(university=university, **validated_data)
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I didn't get your point. The question is, how do I assign a specific value (for example, 666) in those cases when a client (say, mobile app), provides an invalid value for university.

Comment: Aneesh, will have a go today